# Perform aggregation in Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I am storing the (time series) values in `Bigtable` and I have come across a use case where I need to apply a `filter` on these values and perform an aggregation. I am using the following configuration to get the `connection` to `Bigtable` (to perform range scan etc):

```
Connection connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(projectId, instanceId);
Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableId)); 

table.getScanner(<a scanner with filter>);
```

This helps me with `ResultScanner` and I can iterate the rows. However, what I want to do is, perform an aggregation on certain columns and get the values. An SQL equivalent of what I want to do would be this:

```
SELECT SUM(A), SUM(B)
FROM table
WHERE C = D;
```

To do the same in `HBase`, I came across `AggregationClient` (javadoc [here](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/coprocessor/AggregationClient.html)), however, it requires `Configuration` and I need something that runs off `Bigtable` (so that I don't need to use the low level Hbase APIs).

I checked the documentation and couldn't find anything (in Java) that could do this. Can anyone share an example to perform `aggregation` with (non row key or any) filters on BigTable.

Answer (score 2):

Bigtable does not natively have any aggregation mechanisms.  In addition, Bigtable has difficulty processing `WHERE C = D`, so that type of processing is generally better done on the client side.

`AggregationClient` is an HBase coprocessor.  Cloud Bigtable does not support coprocessors.

If you want to use Cloud Bigtable for this type of aggregation, you'll have to use `table.scan()` and your own logic.  If the scale is large enough, you would have to use Dataflow or BigQuery to perform the aggregations.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
PCollection<TableRow> rows = p.apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows()
  .fromQuery("SELECT A, B FROM table;"));

PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> valuesA =
  rows.apply(
    MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(
      TypeDescriptors.strings(),
      TypeDescriptors.integers()))
      .via((TableRow row) -> KV.of(
        "A", (Integer) row.getF().get(0).getV())));

PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> valuesB =
  rows.apply(
    MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(
      TypeDescriptors.strings(),
      TypeDescriptors.integers()))
      .via((TableRow row) -> KV.of(
        "B", (Integer) row.getF().get(1).getV())));

PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> sums =
  PCollectionList.of(sumOfA).and(sumOfB)
    .apply(Flatten.pCollections())
    .apply(Sum.integersPerKey());
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. This means everything will be retrieved from `BigQuery` or `Bigtable` and aggregation will be performed in the dataflow. Can we not calculate `sum` in Bigtable itself and retrieve the value?